# Javascript addEventListener trouble

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Does this code work for anyone else. For the longest time adding an event listener hasn't worked.

```
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script>
    window.onload = init();

    function init() {
        svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
        svg[0].addEventListener('click', mouseClick, false);
    }

    function mouseClick() {
        alert('mouseClicked');
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<svg><rect x="100" y="100" width="200" height="75"/></svg>

</body>
```

For every project I've worked on, I've had to use an alternative method. Am I doing something wrong with "addEventListener"? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
window.onload = init();
```

By including the brackets, you're calling the function at that point, so what you're doing is assigning the result of a call to init to window.onload.
You need:

```
window.onload = init;
```

which will assign the function init to window.onload.

Comment: Thanks! It seamed to be working because I tested it using an alert and it showed the alert. I guess it was just doing it before it actually loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`init()` calls the function and unless it returns a function, this will not work. What you need to do is pass the function, not the return value thereof:

> ```
> window.onload = init;
> ```